# How to Count Instances in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation

If I want to sum up numerical values in MongoDB I do it like this:

```
totalOpenBalance: {
  $sum: "$openBalance"
} // sum up all "openBalance" values
```

But what I'm wondering is, what operator do I use when I want to sum up instances of something? Say if I have a property such as `customer_id`, and data that looks like this:

```
{
   "customer_id" : 445,
   "other_prop" : value
},
{
   "customer_id" : 446,
   "other_prop" : value
},
```

Note that I don't want to sum up the values assigned to "customer_id", but rather tally up how many instances of "customer_id" are in the collection of data. In other words, according to the data above, I should get "2" as my output. What operator do I use to do that?

To clarify, this is a step I need to add to an aggregation pipeline I'm using to generate a mongo view.

Comment: `db.collection.find( { customer_id: { $exists: true } } ).count()` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any of the below should get you going:

Simple `find`:

```
db.collection.find({
    "customer_id": { $exists: true }
}).count()
```

Aggregate with `$count`:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "customer_id": { $exists: true }
    }
}, {
    $count: "numberOfInstances"
})
```

Aggregate with `$group`:

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "customer_id": { $exists: true }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        "numberOfInstances": { $sum: 1 } // count instances
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `find` and `$exists` and then count the returned rows

```
db.collection.find( { customer_id: { $exists: true } } ).count()
```

Or if you want to use aggregate (which I don't think you should do for such simple task) this is how you can do it.

```js
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        "customer_id": {
            $exists: true
        }
    }
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: null,
        "total": {
            $sum: 1
        } 
    }
})
```

Here `total` property will give you the number of instances containing `customer_id` in them